# Decomposition of Hamiltonian in continuous time

Tags: quantum-mechanics, hamiltonian

I have a continuous system where the Hamiltonian operator can be decomposed into two parts

$$\hat{H} = \hat{H}_1 + \hat{H}_2, $$

with $H_2$ containing all the operators of second order (that is second order partial derivatives) and $H_1$ all the operators of first order (that is first order partial derivatives).

Let us now consider another differential operator $\hat{A}$ which, like $\hat{H}$, can be decomposed in two parts, one containing the first order partial derivatives and the second order ones.

The operator $\hat{A}$ is such that

$$\hat{A}_2 = - \hat{H}_2$$

and

$$\hat{A}_1 = \hat{H}_1 \, .$$

Does the operator $\hat{A}$ represent any known physical quantity or operator (e.g. the Lagrangian)?

Comment: Changing the sign on the $d^2/dx^2$ term makes it unbounded below.

Comment: Ok, and so what?  Sorry, but I do not see how this might answer my question...